AWS Cognito: How to approve Pre-Sign-Up event when email already existed on Cognito, but not existed in DB
I have a problem with Cognito Service.
I have an application called Application A using the same database with another application called Application B.
Application A uses AWS Cognito to Authenticate, but Application B does not. And only Application B can change email (just on Database).
So now, when I change my account with email A@gmail.com to B@gmail.com, B@gmail.com can login to Application A like old account (I already handle it) but I can't register a new account for A@gmail.com. It throws "this email already exists" (on cognito, not in the Database).
How to I allow registration of a new account for A@gmail.com?
I think I have to check if email existed on Cognito (Pre Sign Up event) but not in Database so just ignore and go to next step of register. Or should I delete the old email and re-created that email again?
Thank you.
